# Coding Bat Array Medium Level in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
   sum67([1, 2, 2]) → 5
 sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) → 5
 sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) → 4
```

Comment: Give it a try yourself first. If you have trouble, show us what you tried and we will help you.

Comment: Your question looks like a homework in some entry level course. Do yourself a favor and solve it on your own. StackOverflow's purpose is for real life problems, not for helping with homework. (I didn't vote you down, but this is probably the reason others did).

Comment: public int sum67(int[] nums) {
  int sum=0;
  if(nums.length==0)
  return 0;
  
  if(nums.length==1)
  return nums[0];
  int i ;
  for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
   
    if(nums[i]==6)
    {
    i++;
    while(nums[i]!=7)
    {
      
      i++;
    
      
    }
    i++;
    }
    
    sum = sum+nums[i];
}

sum = sum+nums[nums.length-1];

return sum;
}

Comment: @uoyilmaz  have a look at my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and there are a few things you should fix:

- You should check that `i<nums.length` if there is a possibility that a there won't be a 7 after a 6 until the end of the array.
- You should also check that `i<nums.length` before `sum = sum+nums[i];`, as 7 can be the last element in your array and your index is now one past the last element of the array. In fact, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for your second example if you don't check it.
- `sum = sum+nums[nums.length-1];` is not necessary. How do you even know it should be included in your sum?

After fixing the above points, your code should look like this:

```
public static int sum67( int[] nums)
{
    int sum = 0;

    if(nums.length==0)
        return 0;
    if(nums.length==1)
        return nums[0];

    int i ;
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]==6)
        {
            i++;
            while(i<nums.length && nums[i]!=7)
            {
                i++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if(i<nums.length)
        {
            sum = sum+nums[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, it is a little bit messy and can be refactored. I think the code below is much better.

```
public static int sum67( int[] nums)
{
    int sum = 0;
    boolean add = true;

    for( int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if( add && nums[i] == 6 || !add && nums[i] == 7)
        {
            add = !add;
            continue;
        }

        if( add)
            sum += nums[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```